# How to remove '\n' in my regex?

Tags: c++, regex

I have this text:

```
"('John', 0.55)\n"
```

regex: `[^\n]([A-z]+)`

and would like to only keep the name John (no quotes or whatsoever).
I managed to obtain John, but I also get the \n unfortunately: 
http://www.regextester.com/?fam=98328

How can I remove the latter?

Thanks

Comment: The `[A-Za-z]+` is enough. Note that [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970). Your string has a newline, not `\n` (your regex fiddle is wrong).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I still get that 'n' at the end

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew on a sidenote I usually write [A-z], which already seems to capture *all* capitals and small letters, How does [A-Za-z] differ? http://www.regextester.com/?fam=98329

Comment: As explained in the linked answer, `[A-z]` also captures non-letters which have ASCII codes between `Z` and `a` while `[A-Za-z]` captures *only* letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine uqing Qt (as you indicated C++)

`[A-Za-z]+` returned John

```
QRegExp re("[A-Za-z]+");
QString a = "('John', 0.55)\n";

int pos = re.indexIn(a);
QStringList list = re.capturedTexts();
qDebug()<<"list: "<<list;
```

Returns: `list:  ("John")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:.|\\r?\\n)*
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string starts always with "(' you could use this one:

```
(?<=(?:["(']{3}))[A-Za-z0-9_]+
```